# List files in folder and let users send to server using React

Tags: reactjs

Im quite new to React. Im struggling to find code that allows users to see a list of files in a directory eg Unix ls -l and then after that move them to a different location using React. Mist ecamples i have seen are asking users to browse files on a folder which is the same as granting them Samba. We want everything to be done in a web-browser.

Comment: Websites currently don't have permissions to list files or folders in the users system, they work in a sandboxed environment

Comment: Assuming you want to browse the servers system its possible, but you would then get the list of files serverside. Anyhow, your question both lacks a clear definition, and what you have tried so far. Without any of that, it would be a lot of back and forth questions in the comments. Feel free to [edit] your question with as much info and things you have tried, see for example the [help/on-topic]

Comment: I would like different users to access shared storage anf transfer files from to a different storage location. Its basically a file move. send_file_directory doesnt shoe a list of files

Comment: You can not access to directories with front-end code ! you must get help of back-end and database ...

Comment: @Alex, how come i can browse the files on my file system. The main reason im asking is my users will be viewing about 500 Xml files which look very similar. I want to simplify that.

Comment: @user210912 Browsing the files with file input is a different purpose than accessing to files and directories with front-end ! you have not access to write and read file or directories with JavaScript ...